# Exporting a field from mySQL query in PHP code to a .txt file

Tags: php, mysql, file, download, save

I want to be able to export 1 field that is returned from a mySQLi query within my PHP code to a new .txt file that will be auto-downloaded from the web page.

I ahve already returned the query but struggled to get it to find the exact field and then create a new file from the memory.

I do not want to use OUTFILE or any other similar method which saves files on the server side.

Please can someone give me example of it working with mysqli functions in PHP.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: use a header, and/or possibly catching content with output buffering

Comment: Also, check [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: can you please post your relevant code -- the part where you get the query results and are having trouble finding the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, complete with the MySQLi code as you requested. Obviously you'll need to replace the field name(s), table name, data, and filename.

```
//Get value(s) from database
if ($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT field FROM table WHERE something = ?')){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $var);
    $var = 'data';
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($field);

    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.txt');

    //Export values to file download
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $field."\n";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.txt";');
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');

echo $field; // content of txt file
```

Make sure you do not `echo` something above the `header()`